# HP envy 15, Boot from usb

Tags: boot, uefi, live-usb, hp

I'm trying to boot a live usb from an HP envy 15 but I can' seem to do it.

I have already entered the bios setup, disabled secure boot, enabled legacy support.

But, the bios sasys that when legacy support is enabled, uefi devices will take precedence over legacy ones.

So when booting, I want to boot in legacy mode form the usb, but instead a pseuo-file manager appears looking for a eif file to boot from.

Am I missing something? I can't seem to be able to boot from the usb in legacy mode.

Answer (score 1):

**You should not disable Secure boot, nor enable legacy support for Ubuntu to work.**

Go into BIOS and reset to default, I believe <kbd>F10</kbd> does that. After powering on tap <kbd>F9</kbd> to select boot device. If this doesn't work, then remake bootable ISO using [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

### Making Bootable USB using UNetbootin

If using Windows, run the file, select an ISO file or a distribution to download, select a target drive (USB Drive or Hard Disk), then reboot once done. If your USB drive doesn't show up, reformat it as FAT32.

#### Choosing `Distribution` or `Diskimage`

There has been some confusion between Distribution and Diskimage and I am going to clear the uncertainties before hand.

Distribution

There is a Radio button with the text Distribution next to it. If you don't have a Diskimage then you would select this option so the image would be downloaded.

Diskimage

On the other hand, there is another Radio button at the bottom with the text Diskimage next to it. You would select this option if you have an image ISO file and you don't need to download an ISO.